# Dynamically change URL based on current URL in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm currently building my very first own project, a web application with Flask which interacts with the Spotify API. Authorization of Spotify users is done by using OAuth2 and a callback route in my flask app. Until yesterday I have always developed and tested on localhost, but I've now deployed the app on heroku and split it up between a development and production environment. This also means I had to whitelist **2 different redirect URI's** on my Spotify dashboard.

The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to **dynamically change the redirect URI** in my Flask app.
When I'm pushing changes to the staging environment I would like the Flask app to **recognize which URL it's currently on and change the redirect URI accordingly**.
I've tried to use the **request.url** and **request.base_url** but both don't seem to fulfill my needs.

I currently have:

```py
# ------------- Server-side Parameters -------------
#CLIENT_SIDE_URL = "https://my-spotify-statistics.herokuapp.com"
#CLIENT_SIDE_URL = "https://intense-sea-06332.herokuapp.com"
CLIENT_SIDE_URL = request.url
REDIRECT_URI = "{}/callback/q".format(CLIENT_SIDE_URL)
```

Is it in some way possible to do this purely in Flask? Or is working with different Git branches the Go-To way to work around this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to setup CLIENT_SIDE_URL in os environment variables (it should be different for your localhost and heroku host) and in your code read it from env like:

```
REDIRECT_URI = os.getenv("REDIRECT_URI")
```

Or you can try to use `request.url_root` to build redirect